# Next JS hide Server Side Component from Client Side Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm encountering a challenge in Next.js. I aim to toggle the visibility of a server-side component (show/hide) from my client-side component. The restriction is that incorporating server-side code directly into the client component is not allowed, even though that would have solved the issue. Currently, I am hiding the div using document.getElementById in my client component. Is this the recommended approach, or is there a better way to achieve this? Because it feeds kinda hacky.

**page.tsx**

```
<ServerSideComponent />
<ClientComponent />
```

**clientcomponent.tsx**

```
'use client'
import React, {useState} from "react";
export default function HotelDetail() {
    const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const handleToggle = () => {
        const toggle = isToggled ? 'block' : 'none';
        setIsToggled((prevToggled) => !prevToggled);
        const dataItemsElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('dataItems');

        if (dataItemsElement) {
            dataItemsElement.style.display = toggle;
        }

    };
    return (
        <>
            <a  onClick={handleToggle}> click </a>
        </>


    )
}
```

**serversidecomponent.tsx**

```
export default async function ServerSideComponent() {
    const data = await getData()
    return (
        <>
           <div id={"dataItems"}>
            {data.id}
           </div>
        </>
    )
}

async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
    // The return value is *not* serialized
    // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.

    if (!res.ok) {
        // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
    }

    return res.json()
}
```